# If dentro do button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Eu tenho este button "Receber", e este checkbox que quando está marcado, quer dizer que a conta está quitada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso que quando ele clique no button Receber, e o checkbox já esteja marcado, que ele avise que a conta já foi recebida, e não redirecione a página,
Este é o código do button Receber:

```
  <a asp-page="Recebimento" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Receber</a>
```

Como posso fazer um if dentro do button ?

Comment: Ele não reconhece este comando no button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O mais correto é fazer a lógica para criar dois botões diferentes:

```
@if(Model.Quitado){
  <a onclick="alert('Conta já recebida')" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" disabled>Receber</a>
} else {
  <a asp-page="Recebimento" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Receber</a>
}
```

Substitua a lógica do botão pela qual for melhor para a sua aplicação.

Comment: Deu certinho, obrigado.